# How to make the garbage collector aware of external heap memory?

Tags: c, lua, garbage-collection

Suppose we have a C library `my_image_library` that provides the functions

```c
image* image_new_from_file(const char* path);
void image_free(image*);
```

and Lua bindings like this

```c
typedef struct my_image_t {
  image* inner;
} my_image_t;

int lua_image_new_from_file(lua_State* L) {
  my_image_t* img = lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(my_image_t));
  const char* path = lua_tostring(L, 1);
  img->inner = image_new_from_file(path);
  // Assume set up of a metatable with `__gc` that calls `image_free` on `inner`
  return 1;
}
```

As far as I understand, to Lua the userdatum looks like it has a size of 8 bytes (the single pointer). Whereas the application's total heap consumption could be dozens of megabytes per image.

And that means that if a program using those bindings were to create and subsequently release many of those values, the GC would only know about a couple hundred bytes allocated and probably not trigger for a while, while the "external" image data keeps piling on.

Is there any way of making the GC aware of the "actual" size of that userdata?
Or is there any other way to improve this situation?

I guess one could make it `image inner;` and copy the entire memory region, but the double allocation and copying seems very inefficient. And I'm not experienced enough in C to be sure that this actually works well for every library that returns an internally allocated pointer.

Comment: Seems to be impossible, at least from what I can tell looking at the documentation. Maybe I'm just overlooking something though.